# How do I profile some code using callgrind_control in c++?

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I am trying to see where my code spends time on many instructions (doesn't have to be time, just number of instructions).

I see many recommendations for callgrind, which I did start using, but I don't see much I can do more than callgrind_control -b -e, which just shows a current stack trace.

Is there a way to find a line in my code that uses many insturctions overall, and called many times? I prefer it to be my code, rather than, for example, the STL library, which I do call a lot -- so I want to abstract away from that, and see exactly which line of my code spends many instructions, including calls to STL.

Comment: Have you used kcachegrind? With a build that mixes optimized and debug?

Comment: Also there is the client request mechanism if you want to control instrumentaiton in your code.

Comment: Note that if your application does not terminate by itself, no callgrind output file will be produced. To use kcachegrind as suggested by Paul, you must have such a callgrind output file. Using callgrind_control, you can tell valgrind/callgrind to produce such a callgrind output file.